# Center stance bonus clarifications

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

There are two things that bothers me with the Center Stance, and I can't seem to find definite answers.

> The Center Stance gives a bonus of 1k1 to one roll, plus your Void Ring.

Let's say I have a Void of 3. Do I get 4k1, 4k4, or 1k1+3?

> In an Iaijutsu duel, both characters are considered to be in Center Stance throughout the duel

Does it mean you get the aforementioned bonus on the Strike stage (since it is the first round where you take an Action) ?

> If neither opponent is dead at the end of the Strike phase, and the duel is to the death, the duel becomes a standard skirmish

If you are still considered to be in the Center Stance on the Strike stage, do you get the Center Stance bonus to a roll on the first Round once it becomes a skirmish?

To sum it up:

- What is the bonus you actually get?
- In an Iaijutsu duel, when exactly do you get the bonus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Terms like *plus your X Ring* will be seen quite a lot, when they happen, they mean a static bonus. For example, in the Defensive Stance, you add the value of your Air Ring to your Armor TN, so if your Air Ring is 4, that means +4 Armor TN.

So **1k1+3** in your case.

You get the **Center/Void Stance** bonus whenever you make a roll one round after entering that stance, and can use the bonus at anytime after the first round. Additionally, during a Duel, you obtain the +1k1 benefit on both the **Focus** and **Strike** phases.
If it becomes a skirmish and you decide to remain on that stance, you will still get the bonus when you attack, but you will have to wait another round before you can attack, which usually is a bad idea and people move out of Center as soon as they can.

Remember that you can change stances at the beginning of your turn, simply telling the GM "*i will swap to Fire Stance*" before making your actions.
You must remain in the Center Stance for the entire duel though, you cant be on Center during the Focus roll, then swap to Fire before striking.

If that makes it clear, i will quote [the Official 4th Edition Errata](http://www.l5r.com/files/2015/03/L5R-Imperial-Archives-4thEdErrata.pdf):

> **Center Stance and Duels**: In a normal skirmish, a character cannot stay
>   in Center Stance for more than one Round. However, in an iaijutsu
>   duel, the two duelists are assumed to enter the Center Stance at the
>   beginning of Round One (Assessment) and remain in it until the end of
>   Round Three (Strike), regardless of their normal Initiative. Thus, the
>   Center Stance bonus will be available on both Round Two (for the Focus
>   roll) and on Round Three (for either the Strike roll or a damage roll,
>   as the player chooses). Rank 5 Kakita Bushi will also get the bonus on
>   Round One (for the Assessment roll).
>
> An additional note in this
>   regard: If both duelists are still alive and fighting after the Strike
>   phase, the duel becomes a normal skirmish. On the first Round of that
>   skirmish, both duelists will emerge from the Center Stance and assume
>   whatever other Stance they choose (again, if they are Kakita Rank 5
>   they can choose to remain in Center Stance). They will get the Center
>   Stance bonus on one roll of their choice on Round One of the skirmish.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain since the rules on the 5th edition don't mention that the bonus is applied to all checks during a iaijutsu duel, i simply assumed the raw interpretation of the text and figured that if you wanted the bonus on the strike phase, you would need to wait for another round on center stance.
All examples i have seen online only apply the bonus on the strike phase, but that could probably be so you guarantee a hit.

Comment: "Terms like plus your X Ring will be seen quite a lot, when they happen, they mean a static bonus." Actually in that situation they usually say "your X Ring is added to the total of the roll" or something like that, hence the confusion.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain but if iv been using it wrong, do you mind posting something that clarifies that?

Comment: I played in Winter Court IV, a game run by Alderac Entertainment Group. Duels take place over 3 rounds (per the Errata). Center stance bonus applies after the first round and in each subsequent one. Ergo, you get the 1k1+3 bonus on your Focus and Strike rolls.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain and Mickle that sounds fair. Honestly the CRB alone never specifies that, but if that's how it works i will edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mickle how about entering a skirmish after the duel? You retain the +1k1 from Center? EDIT nevermind it, i just checked the official errata and it clarifies everything. Will edit the answer.